# How can I insert template specializations using LLVM/Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I've been playing with Clang's LibTooling and I want to use it to basically generate explicit template specializations for any template for which we don't have one. Namely, I would like to insert in the source code all **implicitly generated** template specializations by the compiler.

I used AST matchers to find all template instantiations, and I can get the body for the specializations. But the tricky part is to find the right position to insert the specialization, because we can't just put the specialization at random position, or at end of the file. In fact, it must be:

- Before the first instantiation with a given template parameter set
- After all template types have been seen
- If it's in anonymous namespace, it should be in the same anonymous namespace scope
- Etc...

So, if there's something in Clang's LibTooling that I can use for this, please let me know. After all, the compiler must have that info.